# Can't access private variable from own class via subclass instance

Tags: java, private

```
class A {
    private int foo;
    void bar(B b) { b.foo = 42; }
}

class B extends A { }
```

This fails to compile with the error:

```
A.java:3: error: foo has private access in A
    void bar(B b) { b.foo = 42; }
                     ^
1 error
```

Adding a cast to the base class makes it work.

```
void bar(B b) { ((A) b).foo = 42; }
```

Can someone point me to an explanation about why the first snippet is illegal? What's the reason it's prohibited? Here's what the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1) says:

> Otherwise, the member or constructor is declared `private`, and access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor.

As best I can tell, my code meets this wording. So is this a bug with the Java compiler, or is my interpretation of the JLS incorrect?

(Note: I'm not looking for workarounds, like making the variable `protected`. I know how to work around this.)

Comment: @John Kugelman: Your statement "*Why can't I access `A.foo` from a method of class `A`?*" is not quite correct. Actually you are trying to access **`B.foo`** from a method of class `A`. But according to JLS §8,2 private members are not being inherited by the subclass `B`. JLS §6.6 says that accessing a member through  a qualified  name requires access control to be applied. So the compiler looks if the class member `foo` in `B` is accessible, but there is no such member in `B`. Nevertheless, it kindly tells you that your intended inheritance fails, because `foo has private access in A`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Error message "has a private access in A" is a java bug for a very very long time.

JDK 1.1:

> [JDK-4096353](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4096353) : JLS 6.6.1: When subclass references are used to access privates of superclasses

contains code snippet exactly conforms the question one

```
class X{
  private static int i = 10;
  void f()     {
    Y oy = new  Y();
    oy.i = 5;  // Is this an error? Is i accessable through a reference to Y?
  }
}
class Y extends X {}
```

They tried to fix it and it leads to

> [JDK-4122297](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4122297) : javac's error messages are not appropriate for a private field.

```
======TP1======
1  class C extends S {
2      void f(){
3          java.lang.System.out.println("foo");
4      }
5  }
6
7  class S {
8      private int java;
9  }
======
% javac C.java
C.java:3: Variable java in class S not accessible from class C.
    java.lang.System.out.println("foo");
    ^
C.java:3: Attempt to reference field lang in a int.
   java.lang.System.out.println("foo");
       ^
2 errors
======
```

But by specification `java` isn't inherited in C and this program should compile.

It fixed in 1.2, but appears in 1.3 again

> [JDK-4240480](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4240480) : name00705.html: JLS6.3 private members should not be inherited from superclasses
>
> [JDK-4249653](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4249653) : new javac assumes that private fields are inherited by a subclass

And when generics come

> [JDK-6246814](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6246814) : Private member of type variable wrongly accesible
>
> [JDK-7022052](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7022052) : Invalid compiler error on private method and generics

---

However, by the JLS this member simply doesn't exist in the inherited type.

> JLS 8.2. Class Members
>
> Members of a class that are declared private are not inherited by subclasses of that class.

So `b.foo` is illegal because class `B` has no field named `foo`.
It is no restriction, it is an absent field in `B`.

Java has strong typing and we cannot access fields that do not exist in `B` even if they exist in superclass `A`.

Cast `(A) b` is legal because `B` is a subclass of `A`.

`A` has a field named `foo` and we can access this private field because `b(B b)` is a function in class `A` even if `b != this` due to

> JLS 6.6.1. Determining Accessibility
>
> Otherwise, if the member or constructor is declared private, then access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor.

Also if we write

```
class A {
  private int foo;
  void baz(A b) { b.foo = 42; }
}

class B extends A { }

class T {
  void x() {
    B b = new B();
    b.baz(b);
  }
}
```

It will compile because Java infer type arguments for polymorphic calls.

> JLS 15.12.2.7. Inferring Type Arguments Based on Actual Arguments:
>
> A supertype constraint T :> X implies that the solution is one of supertypes of X. Given several such constraints on T, we can intersect the sets of supertypes implied by each of the constraints, since the type parameter must be a member of all of them. We can then choose the most specific type that is in the intersection

Comment: "So b.foo is illegal, because class B has no field named foo." -- Notice that the compiler error message is that `foo` is inaccessible, not that it doesn't exist. "...access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor." -- As I see it, this condition is met by my code.

Comment: Compiler behavior fits specification, but error message don't. Very interesting...

Comment: The thing that was confusing to me is that an instance of `B` has a field `foo` but the type `B` does not, and the part of the JLS I quoted only applies to members of the type.

Comment: It's all about inheritance. When you subclass type with private members you shouldn't care about your members and variables name collisions with it. Take a look at TP1 test in answer.  And you can add new field `foo` to `B` type, for example. Instance of `B` in this case can have two independent fields `foo`,  one in type `A` and one in type `B`.

Answer (score 13):

You can't say `b.foo` because `foo` is private and thus will not be inherited, as a result the `B` class can't see the `foo` variable and is not aware if a variable named `foo` even exist - unless its marked protected (as you said) or default (as they are in the same package i guess) or public.

If you want to use `foo` without using an explicit cast like your second example you must use `this.foo` or just `foo` which has an implicit `this`. As [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) specified, the `this` keyword main reason is to prevent that:

> The most common reason for using the this keyword is because a field
>   is shadowed by a method or constructor parameter.

When you used `((A) b)` you are casting the reference type and the compiler will see it like if you are using an `A` reference variable type, in other words something like `A a`, and `a.foo` is completely legal.

An illustrated summary of visibility and access to superclass's private instance variables: [image: here]

Comment: when calling a variable, the compiler first check it's the reference type, when you say just foo the compiler see it as this.foo which is legal because this can see the foo variable, when you said b.foo the compiler will not accept it because he check the reference type, the compiler doesn't care where the variable foo is invoked when (unless no reference type is specified)

Comment: I understand what the compiler is doing. I want to know if my use case is intentionally prohibited or if this is a flaw in the JLS or Java compiler. According to the JLS quote in @Alex's comment, it seems to me that my code meets the language spec.

Comment: No the JLS in Alex's comment is about protected variables and not private variables, he didn't paid attention to that

Comment: No, it's about private variables. "Otherwise, the member or constructor is declared `private`, and access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor. "

Comment: but that only whithout specifying any reference type, just calling foo alone

Comment: please see my update answer, in the JLS specified by Alex, the example code call the variables directly, without using any keyword or reference variable

Comment: Where does that quote mention anything about "specifying any reference type"? I appreciate your effort, but this answer is entirely unsatisfactory. This is becoming a language lawyering question, so I'm going to insist on citations of any extra requirements you are implying exist beyond what's stated in that JLS quote. The JLS quote says **nothing** about the reference type needing to be the top level class. All it mentions is the code needing to appear in the body of the top level class, which it does.

Comment: but how do you call variables in your classes ? have you ever called them without specifying a reference type ? if not then you are using the keyword this!

Comment: @JohnKugelman I think perhaps the error message is misleading you. The actual error should probably have been "foo cannot be resolved or is not a field" as it is for any field that does not exist in an object. Trying to look up a `foo` in a `B` is pointless. Only the compiler is trying to be friendly and tell you *why* there is no `foo` in `B`. Once you cast it, you have a value of type `A`, and that value most certainly has a `foo` variable as far as `A` is concerned.

Comment: This answer should be the accepted answer. You can't access a private variable if you are a referencing it outside of the class. "Why won't this compile?" You cannot access a private variable outside of a class's type. "But I'm calling it from a subclass with the code inside the class with the private variable." You still can't access it because your subclass isn't a strong reference type of your super class. It's inherited. That's why typecasting works. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: @Luminous I'm not accepting this answer because I cited the JLS and this answer has no such citations. This isn't a gut feeling, let me explain this in laymen's terms question; it's a fiddly, nitpicky language lawyer question. I'm not looking for pretty illustrations, I'm looking for JLS citations, bug reports, discussions from the Java language designers, etc.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I think that illustration is too busy anyway. I realized this should be the answer after the first 14 words. Your JLS citation, by my interpretation of the statement, demonstrates your code does not meet the specification. Especially when it says "...top level class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration...". Glad you found the answer you were looking for though. I wouldn't have gone into that amount of detail if I wrote an answer.

Comment: @Luminous The first sentence isn't enough for me because the compiler error message says the field is inaccessible, not that it doesn't exist. If it said "field B.foo doesn't exist" I probably wouldn't be here. That's why I want detailed citations a la Nikolay's answer. It's also the reason I posted such a large bounty. I wanted a detailed answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

The [specification for field access expressions, chapter 15.11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11) says:

> If the identifier does not name an accessible member field in type T,
>   then the field access is undefined and a compile-time error occurs.

From the perspective of super class, looking at the types, I'd argue that the member is *not accessible*, hence the error.

I think the case you're presenting is closer to accessing a member as a field, which is shown in example 15.11-1-1.

```
class S           { int x = 0; }
class T extends S { int x = 1; }
class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        T t = new T();
        System.out.println("t.x=" + t.x + when("t", t));
        S s = new S();
        System.out.println("s.x=" + s.x + when("s", s));
        s = t;
        System.out.println("s.x=" + s.x + when("s", s));
    }
    static String when(String name, Object t) {
        return " when " + name + " holds a "
                        + t.getClass() + " at run time.";
    }
}
```

Just to answer your question:

> Kindly explain what sort of bad code the restriction is protecting
>   against.

Please consider following snippet.

```
public class X {
    private int a;

    public void bar(Z z) {
        z.a // not visible, but if was, what 'a' 
            // would you actually access at this point 'X' or 'Z'
    }
}

public class Z extends X {
    private int a;
}
```

Comment: You're inside X and outside Z, your code should only see X's a.

Comment: @Magnamag, yes, but I would argue this way it works is consistent with static binding of accessing the field outside of X and Z, which makes it more intuitive (at least for me). Consider 15.11 of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11, and an example Example 15.11.1-1 - I mean just to point it out, you're just accessing a member of a variable, passed as an argument, which just happens to be of a type extending `X`, but not inheriting `a`, because of JSL 8.2.

Comment: Sure! Actually, code would be a mess if what the OP poses in his question was valid. My point was that the specification wasn't covering that 'strange' use case correctly. However, the link you provided clarifies the issue, specifically: " If the identifier does not name an accessible member field in type T, then the field access is undefined and a compile-time error occurs". You should add that link to your answer, as well as the quote and some argumentation.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that the spec is inconsistent.  As John states, the body of the spec states

> Otherwise, the member or constructor is declared private, and access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor.

and there is no mention of subclasses.  So class A should compile correctly.  However example 6.6-5 states

> A private class member or constructor is accessible only within the body of the top level class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor. **It is not inherited by subclasses**.

This second statement is both weaker (no only if), but brings subclasses to the table.  According to this A should not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Java is finicky about accessing private variables via a *reference type* that shouldn't have access to that variable.  You should be able to do this legally by writing `((A) b).foo = 42`.

Comment: I'm not sure there's going to be a good answer other than "the JLS says so," "the rules are simpler this way because you don't have to special-case 'well, if the field originally came from this class, it's okay...,'" or "only James Gosling can answer that."

Answer (score -1):

We can't inherit the `private` fields or methods. So in your code Class `B` is completely unaware of variable `foo` even though you're accessing from its own class `A`.

Comment: This is already covered by other answers. Also, please cite your sources.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't this what the default access modifier is for?

Try this :

```
public class blah{
    static class A {
        int foo;
        void bar(B b) {b.foo=42;}
    }
    static class B extends A {

    }
}
```

You cannot access the private member directly from an ancestor, that is what private means. Now why does it work when you cast? And does that mean the documentation is incorrect?

I mentioned to a colleague that the java documentation may be erroneous and he points out that you are actually setting the value of foo from inside class A. So everything is correct. You cannot (because it is private) access foo from an descendant, so you must cast. And you cannot do that outside of the body of A.

I believe this is the correct answer.

Comment: I'm not sure it is a workaround. The reason this problem has never been 'fixed' is because this is what the default access modifier is for.

Comment: If you put the two classes in different packages you get the same problem: "foo is not public in A; cannot be accessed from outside package".

Comment: That's correct? But default doesn't just mean 'package private'. It also deals with inheritance, which is why it works in this context. Can you explain a little more about what exactly you consider the problem to be?

Comment: My question is about the code I wrote. Modifications are off the table. I think/thought it should compile, so my question is, "Why doesn't this compile?" Not, "How can I make it compile?"

Comment: I think this is as designed. You can access the private member variables when you cast because you're on the object (just as you could with reflection). If you want a member variable accessible between classes but not to descendents, you put the friendly classes in the same package and use default. All descending classes are outside of that package. I think the thing about java access is that it's really a 'guideline' because nothing is truly private in Java, because of reflection.

Comment: I added some more detail to my answer

Comment: "You cannot access foo from an descendant" -- But I'm not accessing it from a descendant, I'm accessing it from the same class. The JLS says, "access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor." My code meets this rule. To be clear, this is a language lawyer question where I cited the JLS. I'm really looking for a **language lawyer answer** which cites official sources to explain why my JLS citation is incorrect or incomplete. That's what @Nikolay did, and is why he got my upvote.

Comment: Your code doesn't meet the rule, because you are attempting to access A's "private" members from a descendant, even though you are doing it inside the body of A. When you cast, you are no longer trying to access members from a descendant, and because you are in the body of A, it works.

Comment: Where does the rule say anything about descendants? It says the access must be from within the body of the top level class that encloses the declaration of `foo`. That class is `A`. The access is in a method of `A`. So the rule is satisfied, and access should be permitted. If there's another rule that takes precedence, *I need a citation*.

Comment: Access modifiers are not just about visibility within class or package, but about inheritance. Private is not just 'class level access' it means 'not visible from descendants'. Default also means not visible from descendants UNLESS they are in the same package. Perhaps someone can find the relevant section of the documents that covers access modifiers and 'inheritance'.